# Continuous map on metric spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Theorem**.

Let $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y )$ be metric spaces. A function $f :
X → Y$ is continuous at $a ∈ X$ if for every $\epsilon$ > 0 there exists $δ > 0$ such that
$d_X(x, a) < δ$ implies that $d_Y (f(x), f(a)) < \epsilon$.

Book does not prove this theorem but says that proof follows from definition of continuous map and from corollary.

**Definition of continuous map.**
We have $X,Y$ topology spaces and $f:X \to Y$ map.$f$ is called continuous at point $x_0 \in X$ if for every $V$ neighborhood of point $y_0=f(x_0)\in Y$  exists neighborhood
$U$ of point $x_0$ s.t. $f(U)\subset V$.

**Corollary**.Here we are discussing when topology spaces are metric spaces.$f:X\to Y$ map is continuous at point $x_0$ iff for every $D(y_0,r_1)$ ball $y_0=f(x_0)$  exists $D(x_0,r)$ ball s.t. $f(D(x_0,r)) \subset D(y_0,r_1)$

I can't understand  how from this two follows first theorem.

Comment: This follows immediately from the definition.  Balls are the neighborhoods. You need to be a lot more explicit with your question.

Comment: @TedShifrin Can you please show how it follows from this two?I can't understand how express $D(x_0,r)$ $D(y_0,r_1)  $   with $\epsilon$ $\delta$.

Comment: Take $r_1=\epsilon$. Now think.

Comment: @TedShifrin I don't understand how $f(D(x_0,r)) \subset D(y_0,r_1)$ is used in the theorem we want to prove.

Comment: $V=D(y_0,\epsilon)$ and $U=D(x_0,?)$.

Comment: r = $\delta$ ..

Comment: Every neighbourhood of $x_0$ contains some $r$-ball. The $r$ for $V=B(f(x_0), \varepsilon)$ is your looked for $\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a metric space, say $(X,d)$ and take the collection of all open balls in $(X,d)$, then take a basis for a topology in $X$. So every open set in $X$ is a union of open balls. Now, a funtion $f:X\to $Y is continuous if for every $V \in Y$, where $V$ is open, $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$. Also an open ball is also a neighbourhood, so it is obvious. The theorem says

> For every $ε>0$ (equally, for every $V$ open in $Y$) there exists some $δ>0$ ( there exists some $U$ open in $X$) such that $x\in D(a,δ)$ implies that $f(x)\in D(f(a),ε)$. I hope that helps.